# vb.net htmlagilitypack loop of selectnode

Tags: arrays, vb.net, loops, html-agility-pack

i made an array of links

```
Dim horof As String = "A B C D"
    Dim alphabarray As String() = horof.Split(New Char() {" "c})
    Dim urls() As String = alphabarray.Select(Function(o) "http://somelink/list-" & o).ToArray()
```

the output is like this

```
http://somelink/list-A
http://somelink/list-B
http://somelink/list-C
http://somelink/list-D
```

thin i made `webrequest` for each link like this :

```
 For i As Int32 = 0 To urls.Length - 1
        Dim wRequest As WebRequest
        Dim WResponse As WebResponse
        wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(urls(i))
        WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
        Dim SR As StreamReader
        SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
        urls(i) = SR.ReadToEnd
 Next
```

now i have html source of all the links in array of string that is `urls`
and i want to use htmlagilitypack to `selectnodes`from each html source in the array

```
Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(urls) 
Dim wantednode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Xpath")
```

but it didnt work

i try to pu it in the same loop

```
        Dim htmlDoc As New HtmlDocument()
        Dim wantednode As HtmlNodeCollection
For i As Int32 = 0 To urls.Length - 1
        Dim wRequest As WebRequest
        Dim WResponse As WebResponse
        wRequest = FtpWebRequest.Create(urls(i))
        WResponse = wRequest.GetResponse
        Dim SR As StreamReader
        SR = New StreamReader(WResponse.GetResponseStream)
        urls(i) = SR.ReadToEnd
        htmlDoc.Load(urls(i))
        wantednode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Xpath")
next
```

this didnt work too
how to make loop of `wantednode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Xpath")`
for each htmlcode in the `urls` array

each html code in `urls` array are like this that came from

```
        <body>
          <div class="list_body">

            <ul class="listing">

                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted1.com" title="">title1 </a>                                               
                     </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted2.com" title="">title2  </a>                             
                     </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted3.com" title="">title3  </a>                                                
                     </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted4.com" title="">title4   </a>                                                                       
                     </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted5.com" title="">title5  </a>                                                                                               
                     </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="http://wanted6.com" title="">title6   </a>                                                                                                
                     </li>
            </ul>

          </div>
       </body>
```

i want `http://wanted2.com` link in every string in `urls`

Comment: Define 'didn't work.'  Also post a representative URL if it is public. My guess is your XPATH pattern of "Xpath" is bogus - that is usually my error anyway.

Comment: in `htmlDoc.Load(urls(i))` it send to me    Illegal characters in path

Comment: @rheitzman and the Xpath is fix for all links becuse when i try it in single link it work just fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to use **`HtmlDocument.LoadHtml()`** instead of `HtmlDocument.Load()`, since you want to populate the `HtmlDocument` from an HTML string :

```
'urls(i) value has been replaced with HTML string by the following line..
urls(i) = SR.ReadToEnd
'..so next, you need to use `LoadHtml()`
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(urls(i))

wantednode = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("Xpath")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is some library code I use:

```
Public Function Web_Request_Response(URL As String) As String
    Try
        Dim myRequest As HttpWebRequest
        Dim myResponse As HttpWebResponse
        Dim sr As StreamReader
        Dim sResponse As String = ""
        myRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(URL), HttpWebRequest)
        myResponse = CType(myRequest.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
        sr = New StreamReader(myResponse.GetResponseStream())
        sResponse = sr.ReadToEnd.ToString
        Return sResponse
    Catch ex As Exception
        LogMsgBox(ex, ex.Message, , "WebRequest_Responce Error")
        Return ""
    End Try
End Function
```

It differs slightly from your calls. Perhaps something to do with the type casting? FTP vs HTTP?

Nice use of Linq.

You can save some typing:

```
Dim alphabarray As String() = horof.Split(New Char() {" "c})
--- same as ---
Dim alphabarray As String() = horof.Split({" "c})
 or
Dim alphabarray As String() = horof.Split(" ")
```

Comment: can you help me how to put `SelectNodes("Xpath")` in loop to work for each link source in `urls` array

Comment: WebRequest work fine i got what i need from the links (pages sources)
all in `urls` array but i dont know how to use it in html-agility-pack
`DocumentNode.SelectNodes`

Comment: You don't need the agility pack... If you have a real URL to share, and a real XPath target, we may be able to help.